# Dynamic function call parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, callback

## The Problem

Because of (**Why**) below, I need to populate a table of function calls with parameters that are used as callbacks when the user clicks a variable number of UI items in the web page window.

I know of two ways to do it. One works, and is very clumsy, and one doesn't, but would be very clean if it can be made to do so.

## What Works

So the following works perfectly, `want_details()` variously receives 1 and 2, but this approach is a clunky mess for many functions (I need 50 of them):

```
window.onload = loadPage
var dy_details_functions = [];

dy_details_functions['cb_itemOptions1'] = function () { want_details(1); }
dy_details_functions['cb_itemOptions2'] = function () { want_details(2); }
...
dy_details_functions['cb_itemOptions50'] = function () { want_details(50); }
```

## What Doesn't Work

While the following approach, much preferred for clarity and brevity and script size, does not work as expected:

```
window.onload = loadPage
var dy_details_functions = [];

function pop_details()
{
var i;
    for (i=1; i<51; i++)
    {
        dy_details_functions['cb_itemOptions'+String(i)] =
            function () { want_details(i); }
    }
}
```

The result of the above is that the functions get created in the table, and they are called properly when I need them to, but all with parameter set to the value of i after the loop is finished.

Also, just as a more general issue, what seems peculiar to me is that i was declared local to the function. If it's being assigned at function execution time to the function call from the global namespace... why is it still 51? I do other things with (supposedly) local "i" variables after this runs but before the functions are called, but it's the 3 in this function that ends up as the parameter for both of these. If I do 1...50, it's 51. If I do 1..41, it's 42. It is definitely the terminating increment value of the local i that ends up as the parameter for all of the functions. Why is that?)

## Why I Need This

This is all to resolve the problem that I have been unable to find a way for a callback to receive any knowledge of the DOM item that initiated it. If THAT has a solution, then I wouldn't need some form of the above and much of my coding would be sooooo much easier. :)

## More Detail

Comments below talk about an "event handler". When I say callback, the following is what I mean. I am doing this as I dynamically create things to click on under various circumstances...

```
// oi_detailsN objects already added to page prior to this
// callername is 'cb_itemOptions'
for (i=1; i<51; i++)
{
    mycall = callername+String(i);
    sname = "oi_details"+String(i);
    document.getElementById(sname).onmousedown = dy_details_functions[mycall];
}
```

The callback is called just fine when the object is clicked, and clumsy form 1, above, results in just what I need to happen. I understand now that form 2 is no good because JS variables declared in functions are not actually local(!)

Comment: "This is all to resolve the problem that I have been unable to find a way for a callback to receive any knowledge of the DOM item that initiated it." — `this`

Comment: If by "callback" you mean "event handler", then yes, it receives an "event" argument, and "event.target" is the element that initiated it.

Comment: @georg - `String(event.target)` inside the callback results in `ReferenceError: event is not defined` -- I tried putting `event` in the function definition, and I tried `this.event` -- more detail, please?

Comment: @fyngyrz: basically, https://jsfiddle.net/pb9va03n/

Comment: @georg -- **content:** `<div id="oi_details3"><table bgcolor="#77DDDD" border="1"><tr><td height="58" width="75" align="center" valign="center">Details</td></tr></table></div>` result of event is an empty string. If, instead of enclosing the table in the div, I enclose the `Details` text in it instead, then I get the ID string, but only the text can be clicked on. I need the whole table to be clickable.

Comment: @georg -- never mind, I put the id in the TD tag, and it provides the id in response to a click anywhere in the cell now. Thank you so much for the pointer. You can't imagine how useful this is to me compared to what I was doing elsewhere. UPvote(s).